# generic way to test message equality

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a generic way to test for message equality (or even better for almost equality) in C++?

It would be useful for me, when writing cpp unit-tests.

There should be a way with serialization, at least for strict equality, but how to implement it in a generic manner?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194140/generic-way-to-test-message-equality/) by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 265 on 2014-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want something really strict and low level, you can follow your idea and serialize the messages into binary blobs and compare those.
I would not recommend that for any algorithms though.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on 2014-10-07**:
Is there a base class for all ROS message classes for this purpose?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-10-07**:
No, but I think the serialization traits are specialized.